# understanding the min-color: 3 parameter per @media request

Tags: css, media-queries

I wanted to better understand what this parameter indicates,

as I understand it - for example, if

```
<style>
   @media screen and (min-color: 3) { p { color: red; } }
</style>
```

it means that the device only supports 512 different colors.

If I misunderstand please explain where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using this test:

```
@media screen and (min-color: 3) { p { color: red; } }
```

I believe means that the device supports **at least** 512 colors.

The reason for that is that if a device uses 3 bits for blue say but more bits for red or green then the minimum of the number of bits used for the three colors, i.e. 3, is given.

I don't know what devices use different numbers of bits for the different basic red, green, blue but it appears to be a possibility. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/color